# how to sort by Date related display the Records in visual force Page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, controller, html5

I display 20 Records in Visualforce Page, and Created `SortBy:` Date Button. Once Click the `Date` Button it should display selected Existing Records and Previous Records, in visualforce page using in Apex custom Controller.

Comment: Can you post what did you attempt so far?

Answer (score 0):

In your soql querry add Order By createddate, that will work.

Comment: can u please share any related code for This one..

Comment: You please elaborate what you are currently doing? so that i can be able to tell you what exactly you have to do?

Comment: @ koustubh kulkarni, i created 20 records in visualforce page , and i can use SoryBy date , i select Date is today , how many records created Today that is display on visualforce page

Comment: So you have to apply filter dynamically. Dynamic SOQL will be better option. You can write basic querry in a string and based on filter criteria selected such as today, two weeks ago you can apply SOQL where part dynamically.e.g Qstr='SELECT Id FROM Account';//here based on your condition put where clasue dynamically//Qstr+='WHERE Name =: accountName';List<Account> accountList = Database.query(Qstr);